# google maps circle miss-placed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using google maps API. Allowing user to move the circle (drag and drop) and save the moved coordinates of circle.

Issue I am facing is- Whenever user moves the circle and saves the coordinates and then when I reload the map with new coordinates, I find coordinates of the circle moved from the position I saved.

It never happens whenever I drag and drop the circle by holding center of the circle. When I use a point other than center of circle to drag and drop, It considers that point as the center of circle and saves the corresponding coordinates.

How can I limit API to consider the actual center of the circle when I moved it, irrespective of what point within the circle I am using to drag and drop it.

I am using following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'drag', function (event) {

    lat = event.latLng.lat();
    longi = event.latLng.lng();

var coordinatelat = event.latLng.lat()
var coordinatelng = event.latLng.lng()

var coordinatelat = lat;
var coordinatelng = longi;

});
```

Do I need to use center_changed event to get the actual center?

Any suggestion or answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `center_changed` to get new center. Event argument has no any information but object of event handler has. For example:

```
cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'center_changed', function (event) {
    var newCenter = cityCircle.getCenter();

    console.log('center changed: ' + newCenter.lat() + ', ' + newCenter.lng());
});
```

**Update:**

Dr. Mole is right: using `dragend` event will trigger just once instead of many times with `center_changed`. Setting of event listener is almost the same:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'dragend', function (event) {
    var newCenter = cityCircle.getCenter();

    console.log('dragend / center changed: ' + newCenter.lat() + ', ' + newCenter.lng());
});
```

Output if both event listener are set:

```
...
center changed: 31.91761223410637, -107.25973130019952
center changed: 31.91761223410637, -107.25973130019952
center changed: 31.842939049148193, -107.26041549041304
center changed: 31.842939049148193, -107.26041549041304
center changed: 31.842939049148193, -107.34830611541304
center changed: 31.842939049148193, -107.34830611541304
center changed: 31.842939049148193, -107.34830611541304
center changed: 31.842939049148193, -107.34830611541304

dragend / center changed: 31.842939049148193, -107.34830611541304
```

Comment: `dragend` instead of `center_changed` should be a better choice . `center_changed` will fire continuously while dragging the circle, this may be problematic when he stores the center on serverside